# Java add and set functions

Tags: java, python

I'm a python programmer, but currently I'm reading through Java code to get some ideas. I have no programming experience at all with Java and I don't know how it's possible, but I couldn't get any information using Google about these functions.

```
if(pv.size() -2 < j)
     pv.add(j+1, localpv.get(j));
else
     pv.set(j+1, localpv.get(j));
```

This is the piece of code I need to decypher. `pv` and `localpv` are both vectors (I believe they are equivalent to lists in python?), and something is added to them. I can guess that one of them is adding them to a vector at a certain position (`j+1`), but then I have no idea what the other one does.

Can you please explain those two lines for me and maybe telling what are they equivalent to in python?

Comment: Have a read of [Vector#set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#set(int,%20E))

Comment: stop reading anything that is still using `Vector` in 2012! Modern code uses `List<T>` and the equivalent. `Vector` is all but deprecated. This code is terrible on other accounts as well by the way!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Have you heard of maintaining legacy code?

Comment: yes I have where do you think my comment comes from, this isn't code they need to be learning anything from but what NOT to do.

Comment: I guess since he's reading it, he'll have to maintain it. Therefore he needs to adapt to some old fashioned techniques.

Comment: Guys, the code was written in 2006 and i was reading it to get new ideas for my chess engine which i'm writing in Python :d .
Thank you very much for your answers :d.

Answer (score 3):

[add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#add%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) **inserts** the specified element at the specified position

[set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#set%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) **replaces** the element at the specified position

Comment: Thank you , and everyone else who has answered, this helps a ton!

Answer (score 2):

Checkout JavaDocs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html

add inserts an object at a position moving all other objects one back. set overwrites current object at that location.

Answer (score 2):

You can look up the definitions of *all* Java methods in the [API reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).

[`Vector.add(int index, E element)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#add%28int,%32E%29)

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this Vector.

[`Vector.set(int index, E element)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#set%28int,%32E%29)

> Replaces the element at the specified position in this Vector with the specified element.

The equivalent Python code would be

```
if len(pv) - 2 < j:
     pv.insert(j+1, localpv[j])
else:
     pv[j+1] = localpv[j]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one adds a new element on j+1'st position, the other one sets the value of existing j+1'st position with a given value.

I guess the author wanted to make sure he doesn't try to set a value of a non existing element of the list (vector).